# Trying to Read inner key, value from unicode JSON in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-unicode

I am trying to get key value from below unicode JSON is python

```
messagejson={
u'Records': 
[
{
u'requestParameters': {u'sourceIPAddress': u'113.112.10.06'}, 
u'sql': {u'configurationId': u'note', 
u'object': {u'eTag': u'ed3645fa5ee', u'sequencer': u'005', u'key': u'src-1.txt', u'size': 606}, 
u'mysql': {u'dn': u'url', u'name': u'invoice',
u'ownerIdentity': {u'principalId': u'A3UJ54'}
}, 
u'myval': u'1.0'
}, 
u'ee': {u'abc': u'tcCh6T', u'x': u'487DBE36E1'}, 
u'userIdentity': {u'principalId': u'AWS:AIDAIOJ4'}, 
u'eventSource': u'source'
}
]
}
```

Tried by using

`print messagejson['Records'][0]['sql']['key']`

getting error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

can someone help

Comment: Don't use python2.

Comment: `messagejson['Records'][0]['sql']['object']['key']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one level in your dict get.

run this and you will see.

```
print messagejson['Records'][0]['sql']
```

The 'key' is within the value of the 'object' key, so you need to add 'object' before you get 'key'

```
print messagejson['Records'][0]['sql']['object']['key']
```

Comment: Tried it, no luck. Updated the question

Comment: @Charan Well then you are doing something incorrect. I just took your new example, took all the indents out of it, and it works fine.

Comment: Also, in Python3, variable= by itself is incorrect syntax. Not sure if thats the same for Python2.

Comment: ^ This is also invalid syntax in Python2.

Comment: @andrew_reece I updated the post to make it copy/paste-able into cmd.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `object` level in your indexing:

```
messagejson['Records'][0]['sql']['object']['key']
# src-1.txt
```